# Get properties of jquery .append element right after it has been appended

Tags: jquery

This is what I have

```
var path = $('#sprite').css('background-image').replace('url', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('"', '').replace('"', '')
var tempImg = '<img id="tempImg" src="' + path + ' "/>';
$('body').append(tempImg); 
alert($('#tempImg').width());
```

The result is being `0`, but if I go into a console and type `$('#tempImg').width()`, we get the right width.

So, what it seems is that the append is only "loaded" after the execution of the code, I need to use my code after the item has been appended, is there a way?

Comment: You need to wait for the image to load, there are several answers on SO with nice code examples for how to do this.

Comment: When do you call this code? HAve you tried to wrap it with $(function () { ... } ); ?

Comment: The code is called into a $(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some comments and answers here I achieved to successfully achieve my goal

```
    frame_width = $('#sprite').width();

var path = $('#sprite').css('background-image').replace('url', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('"', '').replace('"', '')
var tempImg = '<img id="tempImg" src="' + path + ' "/>';
    $('body').append(tempImg); 
    $('#tempImg').load(function(){
        alert($("#tempImg").width());
    });
```

This worked and alerted the right value
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

You must wait until the image is loaded.

```
var path = $('#sprite').css('background-image').replace('url', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace('"', '').replace('"', '');
var tempImg = new Image();
tempImg.id = "tempImg";
$(tempImg).load(function(){
    $('body').append(tempImg);
    alert($(tempImg).width());
});
tempImg.src = path;
```

Comment: It didn't work, but for what I see, you didn't use the path value in the tempImg creation, I didn't understand what you did.

Comment: The path is set to the src attribute after binding the load event. How did it not work? did it do nothing? Did an error or warning appear in the console? Did the image get appended? Did the alert alert the wrong value?

Comment: The alert didn't alert anything, but using the load function I achieved my goals, thank you

Comment: Oh, yea of course. The alert should be `$(tempImage).width()`. Updating. I suggest you still use this approach, otherwise your IE7 and 8 users may not get the functionality that happens in the load event if the image is cached. The important thing is binding the load event before setting the src.